# What happened when you exceeded the space limit in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

the limit of a database in mongoDB is 32 TB, what happens when I get that limit, what option do I have to continue with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 TB is the limit of the [MMAPv1 storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/mmapv1/) which has been removed from MongoDB as per [MongoDB 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#removal-of-mmapv1-storage-engine).

The [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/index.html) is the default since MongoDB 3.2, and it doesn't have this limitation.

To answer your question, if your MMAPv1 deployment gets larger than 32 TB, it will output an error and would probably stop the server. If you're still using MMAPv1, it's best if you migrate to WiredTiger for better concurrency performance and many improvements.